# How to hook IDbCommandInterceptor only to a specific type of DbContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, logging, entity-framework-6, interceptor

Currently I'm adding my implementation of [`IDbCommandInterceptor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.interception.idbcommandinterceptor(v=vs.113).aspx) to the static `DbInterception` class via a `DbConfiguration`:

```
public class LogDbConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public LogDbConfiguration()
    {
        if (AppConfig.LogDebugLevel > LogDebugLevel.Nothing)
        {
            DbInterception.Add(new PerformanceLogDbCommandInterceptor());
        }
    }
}
```

And this configuration is added to the context that I'd like to hook, as an attribute:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(LogDbConfiguration))]
public partial class MyEntityFrameworkDb // : DbContext
{
    ...
}
```

But this hooks the `IDbCommandInterceptor` to all DbContexts, so I have to check which context I'm coming from all the time:

```
public class PerformanceLogDbCommandInterceptor : IDbCommandInterceptor
{
    ...
    public void NonQueryExecuted(DbCommand command,
            DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
        LogIfMyEntityFrameworkDbContext(command, interceptionContext);
    }
    ...
    private void LogIfMyEntityFrameworkDbContext<T>(DbCommand command,
            DbCommandInterceptionContext<T> interceptionContext)
    {
        ...
        //Log only to MyEntityFrameworkDb 
        if (!(interceptionContext.DbContexts.SingleOrDefault() is MyEntityFrameworkDb))
        {
            return;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

I would prefer if I didn't have to do such checks, and only add the interceptor-implementation as observer on a specific context. I haven't been able to figure out a way to do that though. [MSDN's article on this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464(v=vs.113).aspx) says the following:

> Interceptors can also be registered at the app-domain level using the DbConfiguration code-based configuration mechanism.

I'm not sure what the "app-domain level" is, but I'm assuming that means the same scope/context as I'm currently doing it in.

Is there a way to do this that is true to the Observer pattern - that is, hooking the interceptor as a listener to the specific type of DbContext?