# How to set CONTEXT_INFO on Entity Framework connection

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I'm working on isolating store data in a shared database in an Entity Framework-based application. I want to use SQL Server 2016 row-level security but I'd prefer to have my database connections all use a single user. So I want to set the SQL Server [CONTEXT_INFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-context-info-transact-sql) to a store number for all of my Entity Framework queries. Then RLS can determine if the row belongs to the store number CONTEXT_INFO is set to.

The only idea I have for accomplishing this is to update my DbContext constructor to create a connection itself and execute the SET CONTEXT_INFO statement before passing the connection on to the base constructor. I think I could either add a constructor overload in a partial class for my DbContext to do that, or modify the t4 template to generate the original constructor that way.

Does EF offer a better way to do this? I'm using DB first.

Comment: [`SESSION_CONTEXT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/session-context-transact-sql) is superior, as it holds multiple values (avoiding clashes with other applications), stores variants (allowing for safer conversions than the raw bytes of `CONTEXT_INFO`) and allows values to be set as read-only after the first call (increasing security). The problem remains the same (executing `sp_set_session_context` after the connection opens).

Comment: Cool, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @JeroenMostert why should context_info clashes with other applications? I think if at every request we set context_info, there were no problem (even in MARS): In document of session_context, it is also metioned : "SESSION_CONTEXT’s MARS behavior is similar to that of CONTEXT_INFO".

Comment: @MahmoudMoravej: I mean "application" in the sense of "purpose", not "processes". `SESSION_CONTEXT` allows setting values by unique keys, `CONTEXT_INFO` is a binary blob that can only be set as a whole. You can only use `CONTEXT_INFO` for *one* purpose and all code must agree on it; if new code/triggers sets `CONTEXT_INFO` it's overwritten. If your code is the only user of `CONTEXT_INFO`, there's no problem, but with `SESSION_CONTEXT` you can avoid any clashes (since you can always make your keys unique).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like an implementer of `IDbConnectionInterceptor` is able to execute some code each time a connection is opened. That allows me to execute a stored procedure to set the `CONTEXT_INFO` or `SESSION_CONTEXT` variable. My interceptor looks like this:

```
public class MAContextInterceptor : IDbConnectionInterceptor
{
    private static ITenantIDProvider _tenantIDProvider;
    public MAContextInterceptor(ITenantIDProvider tenantIDProvider)
    {
        _tenantIDProvider = tenantIDProvider;
    }

    public void Opened(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
    {
        // Set SESSION_CONTEXT to current tenant ID whenever EF opens a connection
        try
        {
            Guid tenantID = _tenantIDProvider == null ? Guid.Empty : _tenantIDProvider.GetTenantID();

            if (tenantID != Guid.Empty)
            {
                DbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "ma_setcontextinfo";
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                DbParameter param = cmd.CreateParameter();
                param.ParameterName = "@tenantID";
                param.Value = tenantID;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (System.NullReferenceException)
        {
            //log error
        }
    }
}
```

Since this is in a data layer class library, I added an `ITenantIDProvider` which allows the layer above to provide an implementation that provides the tenant ID. This ultimately gets set in my Global.asax when the application starts. It also calls `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbInterception.Add(new MAContextInterceptor(tenantIDProvider));` to register the interceptor.

It looks like it will apply to all DbContexts, which I could see [being problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40382013/how-to-hook-idbcommandinterceptor-only-to-a-specific-type-of-dbcontext), but for my purposes this works. [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-entity-framework-row-level-security) pretty much spelled it all out. I don't know why it didn't come up in any of my searches prior to asking this question!

Answer (score 3):

You not only need to run sp_set_session_context, but you need to force the connection to remain open for the duration of the DbContext lifecycle.  If the DbContext was not constructed with an open connection you need to run:

db.Database.Connection.Open();

to prevent EF from using connection pooling.

No, EF doesn't have any better way to do this.

In addition to the options you mentioned, you could have a centeral DbContext factory method.  This is often done when you need to vary the connection string, or connect to a federated (sharded) back-end.  eg:

public static MyDbContext Connect(string username, bool readOnly)
{
   . . .
}

Comment: Thanks for your input. This got me moving in the right direction. I would be able to pass an open connection to the DbContext upon creation, but I didn't really want to do anything so drastic or prevent connection pooling. All I really want to do is run a command every time a connection is opened. And I think I found a way to do that (see my answer.)